# javascript: alert does not work in any browser why

Tags: javascript

i have simple javascript code  but the alert does not work in any browser
my code is:

```
 function ChangeText(){
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "dorood";
    }
    var students = [student1, student2, student3];
    var student1 ={FirstName:"saeed",LastNmae:"alavi",Age:"1992"};
    var student2 = { FirstName: "mohammad", LastNmae: "alavi", Age: "1992" };
    var student3 = { FirstName: "hosein", LastNmae: "alavi", Age: "1992" };
    alert(students[1].FirstName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting following error which is clear

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined"

Define variables `student1,student2...` before using them when initializing `students` array.

```js
function ChangeText() {
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "dorood";
}

var student1 = {
  FirstName: "saeed",
  LastNmae: "alavi",
  Age: "1992"
};
var student2 = {
  FirstName: "mohammad",
  LastNmae: "alavi",
  Age: "1992"
};
var student3 = {
  FirstName: "hosein",
  LastNmae: "alavi",
  Age: "1992"
};

var students = [student1, student2, student3];
console.log(students[1].FirstName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just needed to move var students = [student1, student2, student3]; the variables you were referring to, weren't assigned.

```js
    var student1 ={FirstName:"saeed",LastNmae:"alavi",Age:"1992"};
    var student2 = { FirstName: "mohammad", LastNmae: "alavi", Age: "1992" };
    var student3 = { FirstName: "hosein", LastNmae: "alavi", Age: "1992" };
    var students = [student1, student2, student3];
    
    alert(students[1].FirstName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the array only after individual objects are created.

```js
function ChangeText() {
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "dorood";
}

var student1 = {
  FirstName: "saeed",
  LastNmae: "alavi",
  Age: "1992"
};
var student2 = {
  FirstName: "mohammad",
  LastNmae: "alavi",
  Age: "1992"
};
var student3 = {
  FirstName: "hosein",
  LastNmae: "alavi",
  Age: "1992"
};
var students = [student1, student2, student3];
alert(students[1].FirstName);
```